# Can a project use 2 different versions of the same dll? (Sybase.AdoNet 2 and 4)

Tags: c#, ado.net, dependencies, sap-ase

I am upgrading some old services.  Some dlls it's using are referencing Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient but new dlls that I am adding reference Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.  I keep getting errors saying "Major version mismatch sybdrvado20.dll. Expecting major version '2'. Loaded version 1" and vis-versa.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue? Is it just not possible for a project to reference dlls that expect different versions of a dll?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Reference both assemblies and change the Alias property of one.  You can find more information here:

- http://www.lloydkinsella.net/blog/2012/07/13/extern-alias-underused-or-unknown/