# Different versions of same dll and EF.

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, dll

We're have a couple of projects that integrate a business system to different external services. "We" are only writing the middleware and have no control of either system. When a breaking change occurs in a new version we'll have to cope somehow.

Environment we're using is VS2013, C# and EF 5.0-6.NN

The resources we rely on are:
 A number of Entity Framework models (model first for now, but is subject to change ). 
 3 dlls that needs to referenced.

The resources have been very backward compatible until friday when we got a breaking change on the datatype of one field in one of the dlls. (Went from int to string).

How can one approach this:
Is it possible to load the same EF that targets different versions of the database?
I understand that one would be forced to load them by different dll:s and so on, 
but then, how should one approach the say linq queries and so on?

Is it viable at hotspots do a check for say the type and recreate the whole LINQ expression?

```
if(typeof(Items.Prop) == typeof(int)){
  var things = from x in framework.Items where x.Prop = 2 select x;
} else if(typeof(Items) == typeof(string)){
  var things = from x in framework.Items where x.Prop = "2" select x;
}
```

Though, this should fail depending on the linq expression evaluation, since we're comparing it to the wrong datatype.

Or should one create a specific executable for each version of the resource using

```
#ifdef __VER10
  var things = from x in framework.Items where x.Prop = 2 select x;
#endif
#ifdef __VER9
  var things = from x in framework.Items where x.Prop = "2" select x;
#endif
```

But then, is it possible to do this automated tools that is provided by Visual Studio. And deployment of the correct executable becomes a problem in itself.

This question might be too loose for stack overflow, and I assume this is a common problem, but I'm not certain how to google for an answer.

Comment: already answered  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553045/can-a-project-use-2-different-versions-of-the-same-dll-sybase-adonet-2-and-4/26559251#26559251

Comment: Nice, could come in handy. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always provide specific executables for different versions of an API/resource.
You cannot really automate it using Visual Studio but you can create different build configurations using the Configuration Manager.
See here on how to adjust the references: [Visual Studio: Different DLLs for configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169555/visual-studio-different-dlls-for-configurations)
You can then specify a build variable like `__VER9` or `__VER10` by going to Project->Properties->Build->Conditional configuration symbols.
These symbols are briefly explained here, but it's basically what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Even if the comment above (Nader) could help solve my problems, it would make sense to build a new resource each time, especially validate datatypes hard through the compiler.
Thanks, now I have a starting point to go from.